# Primefaces - How I can populate a new page with some data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm here to get any suggestions about the best way to do the duplicate of a proposal using jsf.

Basically I can create a new proposal you search for one created. In this issue I add a new button to duplicate some data from some proposal.

1. I search for the proposal that I want duplicate;
2. when I click on the duplicated method one dialog is triggered with some warning and two buttons, one to confirm and another to cancel;
3. when I confirm the action, go to one method to created the duplicate logic.

In this method I use the new window with '_black' to open a new tab with the same 'create proposal' page, completely empty, but I want populated this page with the other proposal data.

Which is the best way to do this stuff? I can open a new window with the 'edit proposal' page, but the URL will show the ID of this proposal and I think that is not good.

Comment: Already considered just a modal in the same page?

Comment: The modal in the same page? Can you tell me more about it please? The objective is to have the two pages open, to compare the values. I have the models with data, but when a open a new windows, how can it start with the input values?  Thanks

Comment: OK, it must be a brand new page and you don't want the request to be idempotent? Perhaps the flow scope is fit. Already looked at it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ya, I need a specific behavior for this case. I think the solution is pass a new parameter in URL and do this h**ps://stackoverflow.com/questions/550448/get-request-and-session-parameters-and-attributes-from-jsf-pages.

Comment: And after, manipulate the existing page (search and show in view mode) to populate and let the page editable. What you think?